# When controls that are placed on a TForm are initialized?

Tags: c++builder, vcl

If VCL controls are used in the initialization list of the form's constructor, the compiler reports the warning:

> field 'ControlName' is uninitialized when used here

Is this really the case or is the compiler making a mistake here?

When I pass the form's controls to objects that are initialized in the initialization list it seems to work at first glance.

**Example (C++ Builder 12 Athens)**

1. Create a new Windows VCL app
2. Place a `TEdit` on the main form
3. Add this class above the declaration of `TForm1`:

   `struct EditValidator { EditValidator(TEdit* edit) {} };`
4. Declare this member variable in `TForm1`:

   `EditValidator m_editValidator;`
5. In the initialization list of `TForm1` initialize `m_editValidator`:

   `__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner), m_editValidator(Edit1) {}`

Compiler warning:

> [C++ Warning] Unit1.cpp(11, 33):  field 'Edit1' is uninitialized when used here

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the warning? Controls that are placed on the Form at design-time are created during the construction of the base class `TCustomForm`, so they are safe to access in a derived Form's constructor body, but I'm not sure about the initialization list. Remember that C++ classes which are derived from Delphi's `TObject` have a different construction order (derived to base) than normal C++ classes do (base to derived), which is why constructing the derived Form's members in a base class doesn't cause problems with UB since this is a vendor-specific extension.